# Get a number by random in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get a random number like: 20, 50, 10, etc.
For oracle I can use something like this:

```
DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 7) * 10
```

But it does not work, because it using the range incorrectly. How to get the number correctly?

Comment: "But it does not work". What is the part that is not working? What output are you getting that is incorrect?

Comment: From the docs, it looks like `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()` returns a floating point number not an integer, so if you want it to return an integer between 1 and 7 you will have to apply a `floor` operation. Idk how to do that in SQL but it's probably possible.

Comment: Damn. It is working! Thx, When I read the documentation I did not note that dbms_random returns floating point number. Thx again for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `ROUND` with `DBMS_RANDOM` as you will not get an equally random distribution as the lowest and highest values in the range will have half the chance of being generated as the other values in the range.

Use `FLOOR` if you want an equal probability for all numbers.

If you want the numbers from 10 to 70 in steps of 10 then use:

```
FLOOR( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 8 ) ) * 10
```

(Note: You will **NEVER** get a value of 80 using this method as [`DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_RANDOM.html#GUID-AAD9E936-D74F-440D-9E16-24F3F0DE8D31) generates values that are greater than or equal to the lower bound and less than, but not equal to, the upper bound.)

---

For example, using `FLOOR( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 8 ) ) * 10` and generating random 10,000 rows with the query:

```sql
SELECT value,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   (
  SELECT FLOOR( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 8 ) ) * 10 AS value
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10000
)
GROUP BY value
ORDER BY value;
```

Will give a distribution like:

> ```
> VALUE | COUNT(*)
> ----: | -------:
>    10 |     1425
>    20 |     1370
>    30 |     1488
>    40 |     1441
>    50 |     1436
>    60 |     1382
>    70 |     1458
> ```

However, using `ROUND( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 7 ) ) * 10` instead:

```sql
SELECT value,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   (
  SELECT ROUND( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 7 ) ) * 10 AS value
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10000
)
GROUP BY value
ORDER BY value;
```

Gives a output similar to:

> ```
> VALUE | COUNT(*)
> ----: | -------:
>    10 |      859
>    20 |     1668
>    30 |     1654
>    40 |     1625
>    50 |     1636
>    60 |     1668
>    70 |      890
> ```

And you can see that the extreme values are half as likely as the other values.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c59899af51727c605a8ef865fe0c8209)*

Answer (score -1):

If I followed you correctly then you can use `round` as follows:

```
Round(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 7) * 10, -1)
```

It will round up any number to nearest tens. Also, you can use 6 instead of 7 in random function as round will make it to nearest tens.

Comment: @Alex.jpeg Don't use `ROUND` with `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` as the extreme values will appear with half the frequency as all the other values and you will not get an evenly random distribution.

Comment: @MT0, this is just an example resolve OP's issue. To use floor or round depends on OP's requirement.